# Cognos not filtering by date correctly

Tags: cognos-10

I have a calendar table on my database that looks like this:

```
calendar_date            first_day_in_week
2013-01-01 00:00:00.000  2012-12-31 00:00:00.000
2013-01-02 00:00:00.000  2012-12-31 00:00:00.000
2013-01-03 00:00:00.000  2012-12-31 00:00:00.000
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000  2012-12-31 00:00:00.000
2013-01-05 00:00:00.000  2012-12-31 00:00:00.000
2013-01-06 00:00:00.000  2013-01-07 00:00:00.000
```

I want to get a list of first days of the week for a given date range.  I set up two parameters in cognos, StartDate and EndDate and am using this expression to filter my data:

```
[Business View].[Calendar].[calendar_date] between cast(?StartDate?, date) and cast(?EndDate?, date)
```

But when I run the report for, say, the range of 11/1/2015 to 11/24/2015, I get "No Data Available".  But if I run if for the date range of 11/1/2015 to 11/1/2015, I get a result.  What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using date prompts? Have you tried looking at the generated SQL to see if that gives you a clue as to what is going on?

Comment: I will look into that.